# Why is my abstract starting from the middle of the page?

Tags: vertical-alignment, abstract

I am making a `scrreprt` document with an abstract right after the title page. Everything works fine except for the fact that the abstract title and paragraph start in the middle of the page... Does anybody know why?

This is my document:

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,german,abstracton]{scrreprt}    
\usepackage{ae}
\usepackage{aecompl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage [chapter]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{abstract}



\begin{document}
\typearea[current]{current}


\titlehead{{University of Barcelona\\ Mathematics faculty}}


\subject{Thesis \\ \vspace{0.5cm}\}


\title{Any Day Now}


\author{Jordi Tello \\ 3210025}


\maketitle

\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\large Intro}
\begin{abstract}

**This is the text that is appearing in the mittle of the page, but why?**


\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents


\chapter{Einleitung}


\chapter{Übersicht über das Themengebiet}


\chapter{Entwicklung der eigenen Lösung}


\chapter{Implementierung der eigenen Lösung}


\chapter{Bewertung der eigenen Lösung}


\chapter{Zusammenfassung und Ausblick}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined this way in the `scrreprt` class. In http://www.komascript.de/node/847 Markus Kohm proposes to use

```
\section*{\abstractname}
This is the English abstract.
```

in this case to be able to typeset an English and a German abstract on a single page. Maybe this helps you as well.

Comment: Was a good solution, thank you. Sorry for asking a question which could be answered with "It is defined this way in 'that' class". lol